# Check input text value when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of register page in my project. Example is page to register student info, Enrolment Info,etc.

In the page I want to set button to disable when a criteria is met. This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    if($('#student_id').val().length === 0){
        $('#student_update').prop( "disabled", true );
        $('#student_delete').prop( "disabled", true );
    }else{
        $('#student_add').prop( "disabled", true );
    }
});
```

If the student id is empty meaning there is nothing to update or delete I want to disable else the add button is disabled.

The Student Id is ready only meaning the only way to put value into it is to select data from database.

Comment: you got an error? what is the problem?

Comment: you have mispelled `.lenght`, it should be `.length`

Comment: Nothing is happening no error at all and corrected the spelling but still button is active or disable is false

Comment: can you show the html?

Comment: @Pekka is `#student_id` is a what?

Comment: Please share your html code too so that we can help you better

Comment: The only problem you have is .lenght instead of .length. Otherwise it works ok... can you show use HTML code?

Comment: yeah it works sorry it was because the hover is on i thought when i disable it the hover will also disappear that i didnt know my bad sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( !$('#student_id').val() )
```

as you do not need to check if the length is > 0 
since an empty string evaluates to false in jquery.

for readability you can use :

```
if( $('#student_id').val().length === 0 )
```

You can use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    disableButton();
    $('#student_id').keyup(function(){  
    disableButton();
});
});

function disableButton(){
    if(!$('#student_id').val()){
        $('#student_update').prop( "disabled", true );
        $('#student_delete').prop( "disabled", true );
    $('#student_add').prop( "disabled", false);
    }else{
        $('#student_add').prop( "disabled", true );
    $('#student_update').prop( "disabled", false);
        $('#student_delete').prop( "disabled", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey can you help me again i tried to fire the same code on form reset but it is not working

Comment: Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. If you want to run it every time, you will need to use keyup function of jquery.

Comment: the input is readonly as i mention in the question that is why i am having problem with dealing with it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($('#student_id').val()=="")
```

OR spell `lenght` correctly:

```
if($('#student_id').val().length==0)
```